# Unsupported Module Detected in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, module, build.gradle

Guys I'm new in android development and facing multiple errors a day and unable to solve this one.
This project when i closed it. it was find but now when i open it it shows the error.

> Unsupported Modules Detected: Compilation is not supported for following modules: app, My_Application. Unfortunately you can't have non-Gradle Java modules and Android-Gradle modules in one project.

i go into the gradle files both project and module and these files are showing me courrpted code. as you can see in screenshot.
it was saying file was loaded in the wrong encoding "UTF-8" i encode it to windows-1252. but still nothing happens.

also multiple error are now showing in my other projects also. mostly linked to Modules.

[Error Messages Appearing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xkROW.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Go to  File > invalidate Caches / restart > invalidate Caches / restart

Comment: Worked for me. Thanks. @jean gillbert mbula .

Comment: happy to hear that